# Fremlin Question 132Xh

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure, measurable-sets

This is question 132Xh from Fremlin Volume 1:

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ be non-measurable set with respect to Lebesgue measure $\mu$. Show that there is a bounded measurable set $E$ such that $\mu^{*}(E\cap A)= \mu^{*}(E \setminus A)=\mu(E)>0$. (*Hint*: take $E^{'}\cap E^{''}\cap B$ where $E'$ is a measurable envelope for $A$, $E^{''}$ is a measurable envelope for $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus A$, and $B$ is a suitable bounded set.)

Here $\mu^{*}(A)=\inf\{\mu(E):E \in \Sigma, A\subset E\}$ is the outer measure induced by $\mu$ for any $A\subset\mathbb{R}^k$. A mesurable envelope for $A$ is a set $E\in \Sigma$ such that $A\subset E$ and $\mu(F\cap E)=\mu^{*}(F\cap A)$ for all $F\in \Sigma$.

I just can't find the right way to choose $B$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your difficulty in finding a solution is that there are too many solutions. The interval $[-M,M]$ will serve as $B$ for any sufficiently large $M$. $E'\cap E''$ will have non-zero measure, because $E$ isn't measurable, and then countable additivity tells you that $E'\cap E''\cap[-M,M]$ will also have non-zero measure once $M$ is big enough.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Right! But I don't see why $E'\cap E^{''}$ must have positive measure!

Comment: Oops! Typo in my previous comment: I should have written "because $A$ isn't measurable". The point is that, if $E'\cap E''$ had measure zero, then $A$ would differ from $E'$ by only a subset of that measure-zero set, and so $A$ would be measurable.

Comment: @Andreas Blass I see that $E'=(E'\cap A)\cup (E'\setminus A)$ and $E'\setminus A\subset E'\cap E''$ but how do I conclude $A$ measurable from this?

Comment: A set that differs from a (Lebesgue) measurable set by a subset of a set of (Lebesgue) measure zero is itself (Lebesgue) measurable.

Comment: @Andreas Blass I see we have $E'=A\cup N$ where $N=E'\setminus A$ is a measurable set of measure zero (by completeness). Hence $A=E'\setminus N$ is measurable. Thanks a lot for your help!